# Does My.Computer.Name always return upper case?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, properties, return-value

Visual Studio 2012

`My.Computer.Name` seems to always return the Computer Name in Upper Case. This is how I need it (Upper Case) and want to make sure it's always going to be Upper Case. I'm trying to avoid using the `ToUpper` method if possible but can't find any documentation on this subject.  Does anyone know if `My.Computer.Name` will always return Upper Case?

Comment: why the toupper phobia? it's a relatively cheap call.

Comment: I understand ToUpper is 'relatively cheap' but I need everything I can get in regards to execution speed. I'm trying to ask if it will, indeed always return Upper Case?

Comment: In general I would not care about speed until you have an measurable impact. I can't belive, that ToUpper will slow you application down. I'm sure compared to resolving the Variable ``My.Computer.Name`` it costs almost nothing.

Comment: I wish I worked with other developers where I could ask trivial questions like this.  Now that I see how it works it does seem like an odd question, please down-vote this question more, I should be punished for this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not.

[Microsoft documentation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-computer-name#1TC=windows-7) states:

> We recommend that you use only Internet-standard characters in the computer name. The standard characters are the numbers 0 through 9, uppercase **and lowercase** letters from A through Z, and the hyphen (-) character. Computer names can't consist entirely of numbers, nor can they contain spaces. The name also can't contain special characters, such as the following:
>
> < > ; : " * + = \ | ? ,

You can change it to lower case as described here: http://www.bussink.ch/?p=1369

Comment: This helps a lot, the PC I'm testing on, it's PC name is all upper case and that's why My.Computer.Name is returning upper case, if the PC's name were in lower case I believe My.Computer.Name would return the same, lower case.  Thanks!